# How to read apache header in NGINX?

Tags: nginx, cache

I've set up nginx to bypass ajax requests (wich have header):

```
set $accel "0"; 
if ($http_x_requested_with) {    
   set $accel "1"; 
}
proxy_cache_bypass $accel;
```

It works fine, but I want be able to cache SOME ajax requests. And I want to be able to set cache time in PHP. I'm trying to use X-Accel-Expires for that and i'm trying to rewrite bypass settings, if X-Accel-Expires header present.

```
set $accel "0";
if ($http_x_requested_with) {
   set $accel "1";
}

if ($http_x_accel_expires) {
     set $accel "0";
}
proxy_cache_bypass $accel;
```

But it doesn't work.... Seems like nginx doesn't get Apache header X-Accel-Expires in $http_x_accel_expires variable.

Comment: have you got an nginx config that ignores them? check for directive: ```proxy_ignore_headers```

Comment: I ignore  proxy_ignore_headers  "Cache-Control" "Expires";

Answer (score 0):

The `X-Accel-Expires` header is a response header sent by the PHP, and nginx only populates request headers into `$http` variables.

You should move the caching logic entirely into PHP. If you don't want to cache some responses from Ajax, you add `X-Accel-Expires: 0` in PHP.

This way you don't need to do any tricks in nginx.